# How to Match 2 rows in excel spreadsheet by 2 columns?

Tags: sql, excel, odbc, oledb

I have an issue where I'm currently using several queries to achieve the outcome I want, but when run on larger spreadsheets it slows down substantially. Some info:

- The Excel workbook in question has the `.xlsx` extension;
- The two sheets in the Excel file are `Matched` and `Unmatched';
- Connection type can use either *ODBC* or *OleDB*;
- All data that needs to be matched is located on one sheet in Excel;
- Matched data needs to be in pairs so must equal 2;
- The 2 columns to be matched are **Receipt** and **Amount** where the **Receipt** on the two rows *must match exactly* and the **Amount** value for both rows *must balance or equal* `0`. One **Amount** value will have a negative sign (`-`) at the beginning of it so the amounts can be added together to balance out, but they are on separate rows;
- The number of rows can range from a couple hundred to several thousand (~60,000); and
- If the two rows match/balance by **Receipt** *and* **Amount**, then they need to be moved into the `Matched` sheet in the same Excel file.
- Scripts are not out of the question, VBScript and Powershell are welcome.

Example:

[image: Example Excel Image]

As you can see in the Excel example, I need to match 2 rows where the **Receipt** value matches exactly, and the **Amount** values balance. If both conditions are met, then I need to insert said rows into the `Matched` sheet. So in this example, both rows with `101010` in the **Receipt** column (rows 2 and 3) have amounts that balance in the **Amount** column, so they would be moved to `Matched` as both conditions are met. The remaining two values in **Receipt** match, but their **Amount** values do not balance, so the conditions would *not* be met for them.

The limitations are the statements available to the ODBC and OleDB connections. I am currently using several queries to match and return the row count of the above conditions and if it equals two, then I know to insert all rows of that **Receipt** number into the `Matched` sheet; however, like I said, I need it to be more efficient and to perform faster.

Comment: I think you're going to find a lot of limitations trying to do this in Excel, rather than a true SQL/BI platform.

Comment: I know, but unfortunately I can't change that so I have to find the best option with what I can work with.

Comment: Have you tried approaching this with VBA that would look through the rows, find the matches, and move them?

Comment: Use VBA, it's tailor made for this sort of thing...

Comment: I have to use NICE RPA (Robotic Process Automation) tool. However running a script, whether that be VBScript or powershell is not out of the question.

Comment: I feel like you're leaving something out of your problem description. It sounds like you're trying to integrate this spreadsheet with something external, but you haven't really specified what that is.

Comment: The external part is that the excel workbook is being handled by an RPA tool and thus the workbook is automated.

Comment: I assume that RPA is where the SQL is being executed (so all the Excel sheet does is stores the raw data)? It would help if you showed the SQL that you're using. You've provided a great deal of information, but a lot of it isn't particularly relevant to the issue at hand. Without information about the architecture of your system, how you have the ODBC connection configured, or what your SQL looks like, it's tough to provide assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBA suggestion - it expects the original data to be in a tab called 'Original' and will sort on Receipt, then do a couple of formulas to determine receipt#'s that tally to zero then creates a new tab called 'Match' with matched receipt rows and another called 'Unmatch' with unmatched receipts.

```
    Sub TallySplit()
        vLR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Original").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Original").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A" & vLR), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending,         DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Original").Sort
            .SetRange Range("A1:D" & vLR)
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        Range("E2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C[-4]=RC[-4],R[-1]C[-3] + RC[-3],RC[-3])"
        Range("E2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E" & vLR)
        Range("E2:E" & vLR).Select
        Range("F2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-5]=R[1]C[-5],R[1]C,RC[-1])"
        Range("F2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F" & vLR)
        Range("F2:F" & vLR).Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$" & vLR).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="<>0", _
            Operator:=xlAnd
        Range("A1:D" & vLR).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets.Add.Name = "Unmatch"
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("Original").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$" & vLR).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=0", _
            Operator:=xlAnd
        Range("A1:D" & vLR).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets.Add.Name = "Match"
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
    End Sub
```